# Simulated Maximum Likelihood in R, MaxLik

Tags: r

I am trying to estimate a model by simulated maximum likelihood via the MaxLik package in R. Unfortunately, with increasing data size, I am running into serious performance problems. Can anyone advice about the following:

Is there a way to speed up my code (it's already vectorized, so I am kind of clueless how to improve it further)?
Is there a way to implement the optimization process via Rcpp in order to speed it up?
Is there any smarter way to implement simulated maximum likelihood with a custom made likelihood function?

I have already tried doParallel on an AWS instance, but that does not significantly speed up the process.

I have created a reproducable example and commented the most important parts:

```
#create data:
#Binary DV (y), 10 IDV (V3 - V12), 50 groups (g), with 100 sequential observations each (id)
set.seed(123)
n <- 5000
p <- 10
x <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), n)
g <- rep(seq(1:(n/100)),each=100)
id <- rep(seq(1:(n/max(g))),max(g))
beta <- runif(p)
xb <- c(x %*% beta)
p <- exp(xb) / (1 + exp(xb))
y <- rbinom(n, 1, p)
data <- as.data.table(cbind(id,y,x,g))

#Find starting values for MaxLik via regular glm
standard <-
  glm(
    y  ~ 
      V3 +
      V4 +
      V5 +
      V6 +
      V7 +
      V8 +
      V9 +
      V10 +
      V11 +
      V12,
    data = data,
    family = binomial(link = "logit")
  )
summary(standard)

#set starting values for MaxLik
b <- c(standard$coefficients,sd_V3=0.5,sd_V4=0.5)

#draw 50 x # of groups random values from a normal distribution
draws <- 50
#for each g in the data, 50 randomvalues are drawn
rands <- as.data.table(cbind(g=rep(g,each=draws),matrix(rnorm(length(g)*draws,0,1),length(g)*draws,2)))
colnames(rands) <- c("g","SD_V3","SD_V4")
#merge random draws to each group, so every observation is repeated x # of draws
data <- merge(data,rands,by="g",all=T,allow.cartesian=T)

#the likelihood function (for variables V3 and V4, a mean [b3] & b[4] and a SD b[12] & b[14] is estimated
loglik1 <- function(b){

#I want the standard deviations to vary only across groups (g), but all other parameters to vary across all observations, which is why I am taking the mean across g and id (remember, every observation is a cartesian product with the random draws per group)

  ll <- data[,.(gll=mean(((1/(1+exp(-(b[1]+
                                  (b[2]+b[12]*SD_V3)*V3 + 
                                  (b[3]+b[13]*SD_V4)*V4 + 
                                  (b[4])*V5 + 
                                  (b[5])*V6 + 
                                  (b[6])*V7 + 
                                  (b[7])*V8 + 
                                  (b[8])*V9 + 
                                  (b[9])*V10 + 
                                  (b[10])*V11 + 
                                  (b[11])*V12))))^y)*
                     (1-(1/(1+exp(-(b[1]+
                                    (b[2])*V3 + 
                                    (b[3])*V4 + 
                                    (b[4])*V5 + 
                                    (b[5])*V6 + 
                                    (b[6])*V7 + 
                                    (b[7])*V8 + 
                                    (b[8])*V9 + 
                                    (b[9])*V10 + 
                                    (b[10])*V11 + 
                                    (b[11])*V12)))))^(1-y))),by=.(g,id)]
  return(log(ll[,gll]))
}

co <- maxLik::maxControl(gradtol=1e-04,printLevel=2)
maxlik <- maxLik::maxLik(loglik1,start=b,method="bfgs",control=co)
summary(maxlik)
```

Thank you very much for your advice

Comment: Have you looked into the profvis package to profile this package. There you can see the steps that are taking a while and could be candidates for further optimization. Some of linear algebra could move to Rcpp but I wouldn't go there if it's not needed.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It is in fact the optimization responsible for the high computing time, namely the repeated execution of ll <- data[,.(gll= ... )]

Any ideas how to speed that up?

Comment: More for numerical stability but might help with speed would be to log your equation and then exponentiate the answer. Depending on how the optimizer moves in the parameter space numerical instability might be slowing it down (eg (1-y)log(....))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to decrease optimization time dramatically (hours to minutes) by changing the inside of loglik1 <- function(b){ ... } to

```
return(data[,.(g,id,y,logit=1/(1+exp(-(b[1]+
                                      (b[2]+b[12]*SD_V3)*V3 + 
                                      (b[3]+b[13]*SD_V4)*V4 + 
                                      (b[4])*V5 + 
                                      (b[5])*V6 + 
                                      (b[6])*V7 + 
                                      (b[7])*V8 + 
                                      (b[8])*V9 + 
                                      (b[9])*V10 + 
                                      (b[10])*V11 + 
                                      (b[11])*V12))))][,mean(y*log(logit)+(1-y)*log(1)-logit),by=.(g,id)][,sum(V1)])
```

However, this does only partially solve the problem, since with increasing data size, the estimation time increases once again :(

I will probably have to deal with this, unless someone has an elegant solution?

EDIT: To pick up on this after a while, in case anyone has the problem in the future... The reason, the script takes very long, lies in the package MaxLik and the computation time to derive the Hessian matrix. If you don’t need that, you can tell MaxLik not to compute it. Since I do need it, I decided to compute it via Rcpp.